# Use if condition in laravel validation rule

Tags: laravel

I have a selectbox(`api_balance` => have two item : manual, auto) and a input(`balance`) in view. I want to check if the value of `api_balance` is equal to `manual`, then it is necessary to enter the value for the input balance, otherwise it does not have a value, it does not show an error

```php
protected $rules = [
    'api_balance' => 'required',
    'balance' => $this->api_balance === 'manual' ? 'required' : 'r',
];
```

I wrote the following code but it gives an error. What is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `required_if`

```
'credit_card_number' => 'required_if:api_balance,manual'
```

Even you can do the following

```
'credit_card_number' => Rule::requiredIf(function (){
        return ($this->api_balance == 'manual');
    }),
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if

Comment: No problem :) Keep it up with the great answers!